# sqlite db path in bundle acces?

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite, bundle

I want to punt my sqlite db in to a custom bundle and use that bundle in more than one project.

I have created a new target from Mac OS X FrameWork&Library -> Bundle, I have build the target and the I have put my sqlite db in the bundle.
I have added the bundle to my iOS project and try to read the db from it.

Now comes the problem: I can get the bundle and read its identifier but when I try to get the path for db I get null return string.

The code to read db path:

```
NSBundle *myDbBundle  = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"myDbBundle" ofType:@"bundle"]];
NSLog(@"BundleIdentifier:%@",[myDbBundle bundleIdentifier]);
NSString *databasePath = [myDbBundle pathForResource:@"myDbName" ofType:@"sqlite"];
NSLog(@"DataBasePath:%@",databasePath);
```

Any sugestion, docs or tutorial about this issue are wellcome.

Update:
It seems that I can not load the bundle that is why when I try to read from it I fail.

Code:

```
    NSError *error;
    NSLog(@"LoadBundle:%@",[myDbBundle loadAndReturnError:&error]?@"yes":@"no");
    NSLog(@"Error:%@",[error localizedDescription]);
```

So the real problme is how do I create a bundle in witch I place a sqlite db and witch can be read from ios app? To create the bundle I used the xcode template under Mac OS X so I think that I have to change something in the build settings, but I don't know what.

Comment: If you look in to the bundles themselves (with Finder etc) is the DB file there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
NSString *databasePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myDbName" ofType:@"sqlite"];
```

should be good enough to get the path to your myDbName.sqlite inside your main bundle

EDIT:
Okay, here is what I did, first, New File -> Resources -> Settings Bundle, create a new one, name it myDbBundle, then right click on that newly created bundle, add myDbName.sqlite in it, make sure that it's not inside en.lproj. Also, make sure when you create a new bundle, you tick the targets to include it into your current target, since this is not Settings.bundle, you want to include it. Then run you code, it works fine.

[image]

and here is the code I use

```
NSBundle* bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myDbBundle" ofType:@"bundle"]];
NSLog(@"%@", bundle);
NSString* test = [bundle pathForResource:@"myDbName" ofType:@"sqlite"];
NSLog(@"%@", test);
NSDictionary* dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[bundle pathForResource:@"Root" ofType:@"plist"]];
NSLog(@"%@", dict);
```

the `NSLog(@"%@", dict);` is printing out correct value, which means it's successfully loaded

Comment: okay, my bad, I shouldn't really hastily answer the question. I can confirm that your code works perfectly, maybe it's that your myDbName.sqlite isn't added properly in your myDbBundle.bundle? or the myDbName.sqlite is actually contained in a folder inside your bundle?

Comment: First edit so I can remove the down vote. You created a new bundle and add to it an sqlite db. How you did it? What are the steps? I will edit my question because I see that myDbBundle,bundle could not be loaded. And I tested with myDbName.sqlite also in side and outside of a folder.

Comment: The problem it was that I crated the bundle form Mac OS x as a new target. Your version with settings bundle is working fine. Thx for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done this myself, but this blog seems to be what you are trying to do [Universal framework iPhone iOS 2.0](http://db-in.com/blog/2011/07/universal-framework-iphone-ios-2-0/)

It describes creating a framework that can be used to package up any files and then simply imported into other projects as needed.

Comment: Thx for answer, I ready know it. What I want is just a bundle not a framework.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3**

`let dbname = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "horoscope-release", ofType: "sqlite")!`